# Stop parent element onclick propagation but allow dropdown open/close and menu item events for Bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, datatables, event-propagation

I have a `jQuery DataTables` table with the `select` option (rows are selected on click). The problem I'm having is clicking on the dropdown button and dropdown menu items causes the underlying row to be selected. **How can I prevent the underlying `td`/`tr`/`DataTable select` click events, but allow the `dropdown` and its menu items (`li a` children) click events?**

```
<table id="datatable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#" class="action">Action</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#" class="action">Action</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $("#datatable").DataTable({ select: true });
</script>
```

I tried using `e.stopPropagation()` but this **prevents the dropdown menu from showing**:

```
<script>
  $("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "button", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // this prevents dropdown menu from showing
  });
</script>
```

I also tried manually toggling the dropdown, but this **introduced weird dropdown behavior** (e.g., clicking one row's dropdown button showed its dropdown menu, but did not hide any other rows' dropdown menus that were already open):

```
<script>
  $("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "button", function (e) {
    $(this).closest("div.dropdown").toggleClass("open"); // weird effects
    // or:
    $(this).closest("div.dropdown").find("ul.dropdown-menu").toggle(); // weird effects

    e.stopPropagation();
  });
</script>
```

I also tried `dropdown("toggle")`, but though this resolved the aforementioned weird behavior, it nevertheless **prevented the click events for the menu items**:

```
<script>
  $("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "button", function (e) {
    // no weird behavior, but now menu item click events are disabled
    $(this).closest("div.dropdown").find("ul.dropdown-menu").dropdown("toggle");

    e.stopPropagation();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `jQuery DataTables` provides the event handler [`user-select.dt`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/user-select) for situations like this. I was able to get all the functionality I needed to work correctly with the following:

```
<script>
  $("#datatable").DataTable({
    select: true
  }).on("user-select.dt", function (e, dt, type, cell, originalEvent) {
    var $elem = $(originalEvent.target); // get element clicked on
    var tag = $elem[0].nodeName.toLowerCase(); // get element's tag name

    if (!$elem.closest("div.dropdown").length) {
      return; // ignore any element not in the dropdown
    }

    if (tag === "i" || tag === "a" || tag === "button") {
      return false; // cancel the select event for the row
    }
  });
</script>
```